# boost thread_group move ownership of unique_ptr to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, unique-ptr

What workaround exists to make this code run? The code results in "Attempting to reference a deleted function". `unique_ptr` is assigned in a loop and then passed on to thread and later got rid of.

```
boost::thread_group threads;
std::unique_ptr<ScenarioResult> scenario_result;

while ((scenario_result = scenarioStock.getNextScenario()) != nullptr)
{
threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&Simulation::RunSimulation, boost::ref(grid_sim), std::move(scenario_result)));
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help a lot as well as copying the actual error messages into the question--not just the abbreviated version you've added so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression instead of `boost::bind`

```
threads.create_thread([&] { grid_sim.RunSimulation(std::move(scenario_result)); });
```

The problem with what you're doing is that `create_thread` attempts to copy the functor that `bind` creates, and that fails because the presence of the `unique_ptr` bound argument makes the functor move-only.

Comment: could @Praetorian please look at the extension of this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611780/stdunique-ptr-in-a-loop-memory-leaks

Comment: @Tims Why do you want to pass ownership of the `Result` to `RunSimulation`? Seems to me you need a container of `Result`s, pass a reference to each of those to a thread, and then inspect the `Result` when the thread completes what it's doing.

Comment: I would like to dispose off Result as soon as it is processed instead of having it in a container

Comment: @Tims Well you could erase the element in the container immediately after you read the result in main. Or maybe you should be looking into `future`/`promise`/`packaged_task` to pass the `Result` between the `thread` and the caller.