# std::unique_ptr in a loop - memory leaks

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

Is unique_ptr being properly used below as intended? The code ends with some memory leaks (possibly false positives? or real leaks?). I thought moving the ownership to RunSimulation where life of unique_ptr would end and newer ones would be created in the loop, however, that ends in an access violation.

Ideally, I would like one of the unique_ptr objects in main() to expire within main() and the other one sent outside main to free up in RunSimulation().

```
class Result { public: int n; };

void RunSimulation(std::unique_ptr<Result> result) {result->n = 0;}

void main()
{
        boost::thread_group threads;

        std::unique_ptr<Result> r;
        std::unique_ptr<Simulation> sim = std::make_unique<Simulation>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            r = std::unique_ptr<Result>(new Result);

            //Erroneous lines:
            //threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&RunSimulation, std::move(r)));
            //threads.create_thread([&] {RunSimulation(std::move(r));  });
        }

        threads.join_all();
}
```

Comment: `RunSimulation` takes a pointer but never assigns it anywhere... what's the purpose of that function ? Also if it would assign the pointer, the `get` of std::unique_ptr only GETS the pointer, meaning the pointer would be deleted at the end of the scope. You might want to use the function `release` to pass the ownership of the pointer to the class `RunSimulation`. (Which still does absolutely nothing...)

Comment: `get` does not move the ownership – `r` still owns the object and will destroy the object when assigned to. And the capture by reference means that `RunSimulation`'s pointer will be to the object that `r` owns when the thread runs, which may be a lot later. (I also doubt that the assignment and `get` are thread-safe.)

Comment: And by the way, regarding the usage of `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`. You might want to check out `atexit` and place the call to the memory leaks inside of a `void xxx(void)` function, or ensure that the call is in the most outer scope after all destruction has finished.

Comment: Thanks @Blacktempel. The example is to support [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By using release, I would have to explicitly free up the pointer. Is there a way to pass on the unique_ptr to RunSimulation as unique_ptr itself where it can end its life? using std::move ends in a runtime crash.

Comment: @Tims You can `std::move` a `std::unique_ptr` without any problem. If it does end in a runtime crash, then you did something horribly wrong. Another option would be a `std::shared_ptr`, though it may not fit the purpose for the usage of the pointer (Nobody knows what you do with it).

Comment: Thanks @Blacktempel. Edited my post to add the std::move() option. It crashes

Comment: @Tims The object gets deleted, you still have to take over ownership of it, else it may crash anytime.

Comment: @Tims you edited it improperly, remove lambda and it will work (as on example from Nasser)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a memory leak, but that's not to say that your code is correct. Take a look at your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    r = std::unique_ptr<Result>(new Result);
    threads.create_thread([&] { RunSimulation(r.get()); });
}
```

Every time you assign a new Result instance to r, the old one gets deleted by the unique_ptr. This could happen before the thread that takes its pointer uses it, in which case you are trying to dereference deleted memory. This is undefined behaviour.

**Update** 
Here's an example

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Result
{
public:
    Result() : x(0) { }
    int x;
};


void RunSimulation(std::unique_ptr<Result> result)
{
    result->x = 10;
    std::cout << result->x << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Result> result = std::make_unique<Result>();
    std::thread t(RunSimulation, std::move(result));
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. What is an alternative to pass on the ownership completely to RunSimulation? std::move() crashes

Comment: It doesn't work because RunSimulation() takes a pointer, when it should take a unique_ptr. I've attached an example with std::thread (compiles with c++14 compiler), but it should work with thread_group as well

Comment: @Tims it crashes because you use lambda, as you can see Nasser does not

Comment: Example does not involve a loop. I added lambda in response to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591510/boost-thread-group-move-ownership-of-unique-ptr-to-thread       .... where another reference to unbique_ptr needs to be passed in addition to the one being moved here

Comment: @Nasser .. could you please add a loop and put RunSimulation() inside a class .. that would be closer to the problem i have Thanks!

Comment: Making RunSimulation a member function will incur several changes in the answer. Could you please post your actual code, so we can fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the consideration @Nasser  .. please find the edited code needing a fix

Answer (score 0):

> Is unique_ptr being properly used below

No.

The object pointed by `r` is destoyed in successive iterations while it may still be used in the thread where the pointer was copied, resulting in undefined behaviour.

> The code ends with some memory leaks (possibly false positives?

Probably. You call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` before `r` is destroyed, so that memory hasn't yet been deallocated.

> I thought moving the ownership to RunSimulation where life of unique_ptr would end

That's a sensible idea. I recommend doing that.

> however, that ends in an access violation.

Then that program probably had a bug in it also.

---

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        r = std::unique_ptr<Result>(new Result);
        threads.create_thread([&] { RunGridSimulation(std::move(r)); });
    }
```

The problem with this alternative (ok, the same problem is also in the original alternative) is that you capture a reference to a local variable, but use the lambda in a thread that lives beyond the scope of the local variable. All threads will be pointing to the same variable and if the threads don't happen to interleave perfectly with the loop, then one thread will be moving from the unique pointer that another thread had already moved from, resulting in undefined behaviour when the pointer is dereferenced.

You must move the unique pointer into the lambda, rather than capture it by reference.

Comment: Edited my post to add code that crashes .. whats an alternative?