# Threaded unique_ptr in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++14, unique-ptr

A variant of 
[std::unique_ptr in a loop - memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611780/stdunique-ptr-in-a-loop-memory-leaks)

In this modified question, `RunSimulation()` is a member method.

I would like one of the `unique_ptr` objects (`sim`) in `main()` to expire within `main()` and the other object (`r`) sent outside `main()` to free up in `RunSimulation()`. Would be great if you can provide a working code.

```
class Result { public: int n; };

class Simulation
{
public:
    void RunSimulation(std::unique_ptr<Result> result) {result->n = 0;}
};

void main()
{
        boost::thread_group threads;

        std::unique_ptr<Result> r;
        std::unique_ptr<Simulation> sim = std::make_unique<Simulation>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            r = std::unique_ptr<Result>(new Result);

            //Erroneous lines:
            //threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&Simulation::RunSimulation, boost::ref(sim), std::move(r)));
            //threads.create_thread([&] {sim->RunSimulation(std::move(r));  });
        }

        threads.join_all();
}
```

Comment: Make the parameter type of `RunSimulation` a reference. The thread object retains its bound data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to pass the functor created by `boost::bind` to `create_thread` fails because of the reason I explained in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591754/241631) to your previous question.

The attempt with the lambda should compile, but it has a subtle bug that will cause undefined behavior. I may have mislead you with my earlier answer, but this is the reason posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is so important. The small snippet you posted in your previous question doesn't show how you intend to use the code.

---

The problem with the lambda is that it only stores a reference to the `unique_ptr`. You don't transfer ownership until the call to `RunSimulation` executes, in other words, transfer of ownership only happens after the thread execution has begun. But by that time the `for` loop within `main` may have moved on to the next iteration, causing the `Result` held by the `unique_ptr` in the previous iteration to be deleted. Dereferencing the `unique_ptr` within `RunSimulation` then causes undefined behavior.

The way around this is to transfer ownership of the `unique_ptr` immediately to the lambda, and then have the lambda again transfer ownership in the call to `RunSimulation`. This following lambda expression does what you want

```
[&sim, r=std::move(r)] () mutable {
    sim->RunSimulation(std::move(r));
}
```

To explain what's going on, the lambda is capturing `sim` by reference (`&sim`) and it's using C++14's lambda init capture to transfer ownership of `r` within `main` to an `r` that is member of the lambda (`r=std::move(r)`) (you can call the lambda's member `r` something else if you want). The lambda itself needs to be `mutable` because you need to have non-`const` access to the `r` data member so you can `move` it when calling `RunSimulation`.

Unfortunately, this is not the end of your problems. Calling `create_thread` with the above lambda still doesn't compile because according to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup.create_thread), it requires the callable object to be copyable. Your lambda isn't copyable because it has a `unique_ptr` data member.

A workaround is to create a `boost::thread` and then [`add_thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup.add_thread) it to the `thread_group`.

```
auto t = new boost::thread([&sim, r=std::move(r)] () mutable {
                                sim->RunSimulation(std::move(r));
                           });
threads.add_thread(t);
```

Note that I can't find any documentation on exception safety guarantees that `add_thread` makes. So it's possible if an exception occurs while `add_thread` attempts to add the new thread to the `thread_group`, your `thread` object might leak.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85c57414fc2787a5)

---

Finally, I think you need to rethink your design. Presumably, the `Result` object is supposed to hold the simulation result. What's the point of having `RunSimulation` store that in `Result` if you cannot access that `Result` within `main` after the simulation has ended?

As I suggested in the comments of my previous answer, you should probably create a container of `Result`s in `main` and pass references to the elements of those containers to `RunSimulation`.